# NGINX return 403 when proxy_pass to http from https

Tags: html, css, macos, nginx, firefox

Need help on proxy_pass which works sometime (nginx version: nginx/1.21.6).

I build a RESTful web and run it locally. It works well without any problems.
I can access all features by "http://localhost:7000".

Then, I config a NGINX server to simulate the https locally. The server config is

```
http {
  server_names_hash_bucket_size   64;
  include                         mime.types;
  default_type                    application/octet-stream;

  sendfile                        on;

  keepalive_timeout               65;
  expires                         -1;
  server {
    server_name                   my-service.foo.com;
    rewrite                       ^(.*) https://my-service.foo.com$1 permanent;
  }
  server {
    listen                        443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate               /opt/local/etc/nginx/myservice.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key           /opt/local/etc/nginx/myservice.key;
    ssl_ciphers                   HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    server_name                   my-service.foo.com;
    proxy_set_header              Host $host;
    location / {
      proxy_pass                  http://localhost:7000;
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, I config /etc/hosts to add `127.0.0.1 my-service.foo.com`.

The strange part is, when using `http://localhost:7000` directly, everything is good.
But, when using `https://my-service.foo.com`, it returns 403 some time (I use Firefox).
e.g. when accessing `https://my-service.foo.com/welcome.html`, it loads welcome.html correctly. But returns 403 for `style.css` which is in welcome.html (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`).

And, if I refresh the page, it returns 403 for `https://my-service.foo.com/welcome.html`. Refresh it again, getting welcome.html correctly but 403 for `style.css`.
Basically, it returns 403 for `welcome.html` and `style.css` by turns.

And, when it returns 403, I could not find the request at my web app side. It seems NGINX does not send the request.

When looking the error.log of NGINX, nothing.
access.log just shows something like:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2022:22:08:31 -0700] "GET /welcome.html HTTP/1.1" 403 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2022:22:08:32 -0700] "GET /welcome.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1881 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2022:22:08:32 -0700] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 403 0 "https://my-service.foo.com/welcome.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2022:22:08:33 -0700] "GET /session/status HTTP/1.1" 200 38 "https://my-service.foo.com/welcome.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2022:22:10:05 -0700] "GET /welcome.html HTTP/1.1" 403 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2022:22:10:11 -0700] "GET /welcome.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1881 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2022:22:10:11 -0700] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 403 0 "https://my-service.foo.com/welcome.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2022:22:10:11 -0700] "GET /session/status HTTP/1.1" 200 38 "https://my-service.foo.com/welcome.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2022:22:10:24 -0700] "GET /welcome.html HTTP/1.1" 403 0 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2022:22:10:26 -0700] "GET /welcome.html HTTP/1.1" 200 1881 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2022:22:10:26 -0700] "GET /style.css HTTP/1.1" 403 0 "https://my-service.foo.com/welcome.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [01/Jun/2022:22:10:27 -0700] "GET /session/status HTTP/1.1" 200 38 "https://my-service.foo.com/welcome.html" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
```

Comment: I believe that I hit a special problem of NGINX.
When I use `https://my-service.foo.com/style.css`, it always success, fail, then success, fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I figured out this problem by changing the port from 7000 to other.

On Mac,  listen on port 7000 too.
Once updating the port, the strange behavior disappeared.